# error when trying to boot from usb

Tags: live-usb

I used unetbootin to create a live-usb of ubuntu 12.04, but when i try to boot it only gets to a black screen with 'SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-1--22 EDD COPYRIGHT (C) 1994-2-1- ...' written on it. I use Acer A0722 netbook with amd-64 bit processor and 4gb ram.

Note that i also tried other ISOs such as android-x86 and they didn't work too.

please what could be the problem, i have checked on some other forums but couldn't find a tangible solution, and i have also tried using usb disk creator software too.

Answer (score 0):

Check BIOS settings , make sure that USB bootable is enable.